# In Python, what does '<function at ...>' mean?

Tags: python, function, memory-address, repr

What does `<function at 'somewhere'>` mean? Example:

```
>>> def main():
...     pass
...
>>> main
<function main at 0x7f95cf42f320>
```

And maybe there is a way to somehow access it using **`0x7f95cf42f320`**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking at the default representation of a function object. It provides you with a name and a unique id, which in CPython *happens* to be a memory address.

You cannot access it using the address; the memory address is only used to help you distinguish between function objects.

In other words, if you have *two* function objects which were originally named `main`, you can still see that they are different:

```
>>> def main(): pass
... 
>>> foo = main
>>> def main(): pass
... 
>>> foo is main
False
>>> foo
<function main at 0x1004ca500>
>>> main
<function main at 0x1005778c0>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's function's [identity](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), in CPython implementation it's the address of the object in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Every object **obj** has a method [**obj.__*repr*__( )**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)
When called, this method returns a string object that is the "official" printable representation of the object **obj**

When the Python interpreter encounters
a line `print obj` in a script
or `>>> obj` in a command line,
the method [**__*repr*__( )**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) of the object is called and the value of the representative string returned is displayed on the screen.

The **__*repr*__( )** method of an object can specifically be called by using the built-in function [***repr*( )**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) with the object's name as argument, to assign the string returned by **__*repr*__( )** to an identifier, so being able to perform operations on this representation.
Only in Python 1 and Python 2, reversed quotes around the name of an object have the same effect than calling [***repr*( )**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) on it.

Compare:

```
def main():
    pass

if  '__repr__' in  dir(main):
    print ('__repr__ is a method  of main\n')
else:
     print ('main has no method __repr__\n')

print ('main : %s\n'
       'type(main) == %s\n'
       % (main,type(main)) )

print ('repr(main) : %s\n'
       'type(repr(main)) == %s'
       %(repr(main),type(repr(main))) )

# Only in Python 1 and Python 2, string conversions with
# reversed quotes produce the same result as repr():
print ('\n`main` : %s\n'
       'type(`main`) == %s'
       % (`main`,type(`main`)) )
```

result

```
__repr__ is a method  of main

main : <function main at 0x00FB2930>
type(main) == <type 'function'>

repr(main) : <function main at 0x00FB2930>
type(repr(main)) == <type 'str'>
```

.

In `<function main at 0x00FB2930>`, the part `0x00FB2930` represents the **memory address** of the object  (here a function), that is to say an **integer** that references the location of the object in the RAM.

`0x00FB2930` is an [hexinteger](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals), that is to say a literal representing the value of the memory address in base 16.

This memory address is precisely returned by the built-in function `id()`, whose value is printed as a [decimalinteger](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals) literal, that is to say its representation in base 10.

```
print ('repr(main) : %s\n'
       'type(repr(main)) == %s\n'
       % (repr(main),
          type(repr(main))) )

hex_address = repr(main)[18:-1]
print ('hex_address = repr(main)[18:-1]  defined\n'
       'hex_address : %s\n'
       'type(hex_address) == %s\n'
       'int(hex_address , 16) : %s\n'
       'type(int(hex_address , 16)) : %s\n'
       % (hex_address,
          type(hex_address),
          int(hex_address , 16),
          type(int(hex_address , 16))) )

print ('id(main) : %s\n'
       'type(id(main)) == %s\n'
       'hex(id(main) : %s\n'
       'type(hex(id(main)) : %s'
       % (id(main),
          type(id(main)),
          hex(id(main)),
          type(hex(id(main)))) )
```

result

```
repr(main) : <function main at 0x00FB2930>
type(repr(main)) == <type 'str'>

hex_address = repr(main)[18:-1]  defined
hex_address : 0x00FB2930
type(hex_address) == <type 'str'>
int(hex_address , 16) : 16460080
type(int(hex_address , 16)) : <type 'int'>

id(main) : 16460080
type(id(main)) == <type 'int'>
hex(id(main) : 0xfb2930
type(hex(id(main)) : <type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CPython is simply the address of an object in memory. All objects have this, not only functions.

Comment: This is only true for CPython.