# Trying to return a function as an integer in Python 3

Tags: python, function, class, arguments

When I try to return a function as an integer, and then use that integer in another function, the argument becomes a type 'function'

example:

```
def makeChoice():
    c = 0
    if input='yes':
        c = 1
    return int(c)

def choiceMade(c)
    if c == 1:
        print('finally this damn thing works')

while True:
    choiceMade(makeChoice)
```

if I debug choiceMade(c) with print(c), I get "function at x980342" instead of an integer, and the if/else statement never is true.

I was under the impression that python functions could be called as arguments so now I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to call the function (parentheses). And you need to understand the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: And add a `:` after `choiceMade(c)` :)

Comment: See: [What does it mean when the parentheses are omitted from a function call (supposing no arguments are necessary)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933)

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `makeChoice`. In Python, functions are objects, and transmitting the function (without calling it) to various parts of the program is sending the entire function object to be called later. In this case, you need to access the returned object, the integer:

```
while True:
   choiceMade(makeChoice())
```

Also, note that you need to use `==` instead of `=` in `makeChoice`. `=` is for assignment, while `==` is for comparison only:

new `makeChoice`:

```
def makeChoice():
   c = 0
   if input=='yes':
      return int(c)
```

Additionally, a `:` is needed at the end of the function header `choiceMade`:

```
def choiceMade(c):
   if c == 1:
     print('finally this damn thing works')
```

Comment: Thanks. This is just a rough version of my code but you're right. I am properly using == and : in my code already though. My issue was keeping the parentheses in the called function (ie "choiceMade(makeChoice())" instead of choiceMade(makeChoice)

Comment: @AlexW "My issue was keeping the parentheses in the called function (ie "choiceMade(makeChoice())" instead of choiceMade(makeChoice)" -- not really

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to delay the execution of your function, thus modify your choiceMade. So that you can still use the same way to call your function `choiceMade(makeChoice)`

```
def makeChoice():
    c = 0
    if input == 'yes':
        c = 1
    return int(c)

def choiceMade(c):
    if c() == 1:
        print('finally this damn thing works')

while True:
    choiceMade(makeChoice)
```