# Empty parentheses for Python function

Tags: python, function

I've encountered the following code to create a user-defined function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_data(n):
    ϵ_values = []
    for i in range(n):
        e = np.random.randn()
        ϵ_values.append(e)
    return ϵ_values
data = generate_data(100)
plt.plot(data)
plt.show() #This is to plot
```

I don't understand the empty parentheses () anywhere in the code.

Comment: This is how you invoke the function.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls

Comment: @SergeBallesta indeed - but the official tutorial part on functions doesn't really explain this particular point.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Not really, but the 4.6 paragraph of the tuto shows that if you use a function name without parens, you just get a ref to the function object, and the 4.7.1 shows an example of calling a function with no pararameters. I am sorry if my comment was read as offensive because it was not my intent, but I really think that trying to use numpy and matplot before knowing the basics of Python is dangerous.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm definitly not the one to feel offended by your comment, which is just plain common sense as far as I'm concerned ;-) - my point was just that there were actually no _clear_ explanation on that exact point in the official tutorial, so nowhere we could linked to (hence my link to the language's grammar instead).

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses are for executing function, also adding parameters for it. If a function can work without any parameters, that parentheses could be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Empty parentheses mean that the function you are calling takes no arguments or it has default arguments pre-defined.

When a function is part of a class, we call it "method".

Example:

Python has a built-in class called `str` (string), to represent a sequence of characters. It has several methods (functions inside that class), one of which is `isupper()`. This method takes no arguments and will return `True` if the string is uppercase and `False` otherwise. Example:

```
"hello".isupper()  # this returns false.
```

What you are calling at the end of your code, `plt.show()` is a method (again, a function inside a class that takes no arguments, or has pre-defined defaults) of matplotlib.pyplot.

You can check the documentation to see all the available functions for pyplot https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/pyplot_summary.html if you go there, click on any function, then click the [source] link, and you will see how the function is built.

Answer (score 0):

Empty parentheses can be used to call function with default or no arguments - but a function itself can be accessed without using parentheses - just it will not do anything. 
Refer to [Purpose of calling function without brackets python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/purpose-of-calling-function-without-brackets-python) .

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses are used to invoke a function. Keeping () after any word means calling a function of that name. Say a function is

```
def fun(a, b):
  return a + b
```

This function, when called, will have 2 numbers inside (), like `fun(2, 3)`. Similarly, say a function is

```
def fun2():
  print('Hello World')
```

This function can be called without passing any arguments, like `fun2()`.

In your code, the first parentheses `np.random.randn()` means to call the `randn` function of random module in numpy package. Similarly, `plt.show()` means to call the `show()` function of `matplotlib.pyplot` module.