# When using the upper method of strings, why do I have to put () after upper?

Tags: python

This is the code which makes upper work:

```py
a = 'Hello World'
print(a.upper())
```

And this is the code which I think is correct but doesn't work:

```py
a = 'Hello World'
print(a.upper)
```

I'm using PyCharm if it helps

Note: I started learning Python today only, so please don't be very harsh.

Comment: since `upper` is a function you need to do a function call using `upper()`

Comment: `foo()` means, execute the function `foo` and pass no arguments to it. If you don't add the parentheses, Python won't automatically know to execute that function, so if you do something like `bar = foo` instead of `bar = foo()`, `bar` will point to the function itself rather than the value the function returned.

Comment: Yes, you do. That's what the error is telling you. `a.upper()` will call your string's `.upper()` function. `a.upper` will look for a property called `upper` on your string, fail to find such a thing, and throw an error.

Comment: @RandomDavis That should just be the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of calling function without brackets python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/purpose-of-calling-function-without-brackets-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods/Functions must be called with parentheses `()`. Attributes/Properties can be retrieved without parentheses. And there is a weird third case which I'll get into later.

Consider this example

```
foo.bar()
foo.baz
```

In typical usage `bar` would be a function/method of foo. `baz` would be some kind of attribute/property/parameter of foo.

In your case, `upper` is actually a function/method and should normally called with parentheses `()`. Consider this interactive result

```
>>> a = 'Hello World'
>>> a
'Hello World'
>>> a.upper()
'HELLO WORLD'
>>> a.upper
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x000001EC70EFAD70>
```

When you call `a.upper()` it works as you might expect. But when you call `a.upper` it says you're getting a method. I make this mistake all of the time when I forget to put parentheses on a function call. I don't know how common it is for other people.

Coming back to `a.upper`. With that, you're getting the actual function/method instead of the return value of the function/method. There are some cases where it can be useful to pass a function to another class or pass a function to another function. You can also use this feature to make your own name for a function. Consider

```
>>> a = 'Hello World'
>>> alias = a.upper
>>> alias()
'HELLO WORLD'
>>> alias
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x000001EC70EFAFB0>
```

I've assigned `a.upper` to something new called `alias`. And when I call `alias()`, then it returns the upper case of a.

Answer (score 3):

(re-posting my comment as an answer)

`foo()` means, execute the function `foo` and pass no arguments to it. If you don't add the parentheses, Python won't automatically know to execute that function, so if you do something like `bar = foo` instead of `bar = foo()`, `bar` will point to the function itself rather than the value the function returned when executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as like this too because upper lower is a method and preset method end with parenthesis

```
a = "hello world".upper()
print(a)

print("hello world".upper())

a = "hello world"
print(a.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

**upper** is a method of **string** (https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

When you call a method, you need to put the round braces, even if it does not take any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

upper is a function and functions must be used as `function()`, where the () delimits possible parameters to the function. Since the function doesn't use any parameters, we leave the parentheses empty.