# Difference between adding parentheses () after a min or average function in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Could someone please explain to me why the output complete changes when you forget the (), i.e this is the correct minimum:

```
data['PRICE'].min()
```

`5.0`

...and this is the output when you forget to use parentheses. How could this be interpretted?

```
data['PRICE'].min
​

<bound method Series.min of 0      24.0
1      21.6
2      34.7
3      33.4
4      36.2
       ... 
501    22.4
502    20.6
503    23.9
504    22.0
505    11.9
Name: PRICE, Length: 506, dtype: float64>
```

[image: attached image example]

Comment: `bound method Series` when you type a method without calling it in jupyer notebook it will tell you something about the method, usually bound method something something which is what you are getting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in Python are also Objects. By using parentheses you call the function. Without parentheses you just return the object instead. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786508/1618893