# Python print statement problem. Print function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try this code, the `print` doesn't happen even if I input `yes` for every prompt. Why not?

```
import sys, os, time

CP = input("Is Cost Price given?\n").lower
SP = input("Is Selling Price given?\n").lower
PROFIT = input("Is Profit in amoung given?\n").lower
LOSS = input("Is Loss in amount given?\n").lower
PROFIT_PERCENT = input("Is Profit in percentage given?\n").lower
LOSS_PERCENT = input("Is Loss in percent given?\n").lower

if CP == SP == PROFIT == LOSS == PROFIT_PERCENT == LOSS_PERCENT == "yes":
    print("Everything is given man.")
time.sleep(3)
exit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean when the parentheses are omitted from a function or method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/what-does-it-mean-when-the-parentheses-are-omitted-from-a-function-or-method-cal)

Answer (score 1):

Change all `.lower` to `.lower()`.