# Elif and if statement not working in and out of function

Tags: python, if-statement

The code:

```
class Car:
y = 0
x = 0
x_miles = y / 5280
y_miles = x / 5280
direction = 0
speed = 100
fps = speed * 1.467
Cords = {x}, {y}
Cords_miles = x_miles, y_miles

def driving(self):
    drv = 'start'
    while drv != 'stop':
        if Car.direction == -270:
            Car.direction = 90
        elif Car.direction == 270:
            Car.direction = -90
        elif Car.direction == -180:
            Car.direction = 180
        drv = input('Say W(Forward), S(Stop), A(TurnLeft), D(TurnRight), C(GetCords): ').lower
        if drv == 's':
        print('this never gets executed, as well as the elifs statements after')
        else:
            print('this always gets executed')
```

the problem is that when I call the function and then enter an input, for example, if I give it the letter s, it skips to the else statement immediately. Here's the output if I enter s:

```
Say W(Forward), S(Stop), A(TurnLeft), D(TurnRight), C(GetCords): s
this always gets executed
```

I cannot seem to fix it, so it would be great if someone could help!

Comment: You're missing the brackets on lower - `lower()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing brackets after you `.lower`. As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786508/13428616), without the brackets you are just setting a reference to the lower method but do not actually call it.

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck trying to solve this for while!