# Temporalis library in brightway2.5 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, attributeerror, temporal, brightway, non-type

I downloaded temporalis library to brightway from terminal. During installation it gave a warning that not all packages could be installed. The error is as follows:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtVhl.png)his behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
brightway2 2.4.2 requires bw2calc==1.8.1, but you have bw2calc 2.0.dev16 which is incompatible.
brightway2 2.4.2 requires bw2data<3.99, but you have bw2data 4.0.dev33 which is incompatible.
```

and here the screenshots from the jupyter-lab for the error code

[code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfTH6.png)

[code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qCo4.jpg)

but since Temporalis works, I tried to get a result for my project using the codes in the following link

"[https://github.com/brightway-lca/from-the-ground-up/blob/main/temporal/1%20-%20Introduction.ipynb](https://stackoverflow.com)"

on github, but then the first error I got said that brightway2.5 is compatible with Temporalis, so I installed an environment with the new brightway2.5 on anaconda and tried again. Then jupyter-lab suggested me to migrate projects in another error, I applied it as well, but I still get an error like this in the line 10. do you know why and how to solve this? any help would be appreciated.

**My computer: ** MacBook Pro 2017 - 2.3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 , Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB , 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 , macOS 13.6.1 (22G313).

```
[1] from bw_temporalis import easy_timedelta_distribution, easy_datetime_distribution, TemporalisLCA, Timeline, TemporalDistribution
from bw_temporalis.lcia import characterize_methane, characterize_co2
from bw2data import *
import bw2data as bd
import bw2io as bi
import bw2calc as bc
import bw_temporalis as bwt
import bw_graph_tools as graph
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

[2] projects.set_current('bw2.5')

[3] projects.migrate_project_25

[4] bd.Database('thesis  0.1')

[5] ei = bd.Database("thesis  0.1")

[6] activity_name = 'copy_Köck building'

[7] my_activity = [x for x in ei if x['name'] == activity_name][0]

[8] my_activity['temporal distribution'] = bwt.easy_timedelta_distribution(
      start=0,
      end=10,
      resolution="Y",
      steps=11,
    )

[9] temporal_distribution: easy_timedelta_distribution(
                    start=0,
                    end=100, # Range includes both start and end
                    resolution="Y",  # M for months, Y for years, etc.
                    steps=10)

[10] lca = bc.LCA({my_activity: 1}, ("EF  v3.0", "climate change", "global warming potential (GWP100)"))
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 lca = bc.LCA({my_activity: 1}, ("EF  v3.0", "climate change", "global warming potential (GWP100)"))
      2 lca.lci()
      3 lca.lcia()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw25.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2calc/lca.py:97, in LCA.__init__(self, demand, method, weighting, normalization, data_objs, remapping_dicts, log_config, seed_override, use_arrays, use_distributions, selective_use)
     95 if data_objs is None:
     96     self.ensure_bw2data_available()
---> 97     demand, self.packages, remapping_dicts = prepare_lca_inputs(
     98         demand=demand,
     99         method=method,
    100         weighting=weighting,
    101         normalization=normalization,
    102     )
    103     self.method = method
    104     self.weighting = weighting

File ~/anaconda3/envs/bw25.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bw2data/compat.py:69, in prepare_lca_inputs(demand, method, weighting, normalization, demands, remapping, demand_database_last)
     59 def prepare_lca_inputs(
     60     demand=None,
     61     method=None,
   (...)
     66     demand_database_last=True,
     67 ):
     68     """Prepare LCA input arguments in Brightway 2.5 style."""
---> 69     if not projects.dataset.data.get("25"):
     70         raise Brightway2Project(
     71             "Please use `projects.migrate_project_25` before calculating using Brightway 2.5"
     72         )
     74     databases.clean()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

[11] lca.score

[12] tlca = TemporalisLCA(lca)
```

[projects.migrate.project_25() error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFoLX.png)

[code with the adjustments 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KElm5.png)

[code with the adjustments 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Div.png)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean when the parentheses are omitted from a function or method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/what-does-it-mean-when-the-parentheses-are-omitted-from-a-function-or-method-cal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Answer (score 1):

You need to *run* the function :)

Not:

```py
[3] projects.migrate_project_25
```

But:

```py
[3] projects.migrate_project_25()
```

If this doesn't work, the best alternative is to create a new project and re-import your data. I think you could also try to make sure that `projects.dataset.data` has the correct form:

```py
projects.dataset.data = {}
projects.dataset.save()
```

And then try to run `projects.migrate_project_25()`

And since you are in 2.5, don't do this:

```py
[6] activity_name = 'copy_Köck building'

[7] my_activity = [x for x in ei if x['name'] == activity_name][0]
```

But instead:

```py
my_activity = bd.get_node(database="thesis  0.1", name='copy_Köck building')
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks a lot for your comment. I adjusted the changes as you showed here, but the "projects.migrate_project_25()" is not working with the brackets. Also, for the other one, even though I made adjustments, I still get the same error from line [10]. I added the images from the code at the bottom of the question, if you want to check it