# different between "return func" and "return func()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-decorators

Firstly, I'm so sorry if this is a dupplicated question.

let's say I have a simple python code named decorator.py with decorator here:

```py
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Before function.")
        val = func()
        print("After function.")
        return val
    return wrapper() # <- please pay attention to this line`

@decorator
def hello():
    print("hello!")

@decorator
def good_bye():
    print("good_bye!")

@decorator
def thank_you():
    print("thank_you!")

@decorator
def thanks_a_lot():
    print("thanks_a_lot!")
```

the result after running the code

```
Before function.
hello!
After function.
Before function.
good_bye!
After function.
Before function.
thank_you!
After function.
Before function.
thanks_a_lot!
After function.
[Finished in 46ms]
```

this mean, return wrapper() calls all my functions?
what is the difference between wrapper() and wrapper in this case.
I appreciate for your explaination.

I'm tring to run on debug mode to find out, but still got nothing, I hope I'll get a detail explaination

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean when the parentheses are omitted from a function or method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/what-does-it-mean-when-the-parentheses-are-omitted-from-a-function-or-method-cal)

Answer (score 1):

In this case calling wrapper() would **immediately** execute the function.  if you just return wrapper, then you are returning the function itself so that it can be called later by another part of the code

EDIT

I am going to come up with a contrived example to illustrate what I mean in the above explanation:

An immediately executed function might be like this:

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello, World!")

# Call the function to execute it
hello_world()
```

In the above case as you expect "Hello, World!" is printed immediately.

You can also reference functions in variables like:

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello, World!")

# Assign the function to a variable
hello_function = hello_world

# Call the variable as a function
hello_function()
```

In the above case we created a variable hello_function that references the same hello_world function and then LATER executes it with hello_function()

You could then do slick things like pass that function around to other functions creating higher order functions.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you help me to understand this point in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

`wrapper()` is an expression that calls the function, execute its instructions and catch the returned result. Thus if you write `a = wrapper()` then `a` will be set to the returned value.

`wrapper` is an expression that represents the function itself, no more no less. When you have an expression, say `e` that corresponds to a function, you can call it using `()`. So, if you write `a = wrapper`, `a` is set to a value that represent a callable function. You can then write `a()` to call it.

If you change `return wrapper()` to `return wrapper`, you can observe that nothing will be printed as the wrapper is never called, so anything it wraps is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

While, a function is passed as an argument, we generally pass the function name. For example, let's say, we have a number of functions, where we will define "we will do this, then this and this and so on."

```
def hello():
    return "Hello"

user_name = input("Your name : ")

def name(name):
    return name

def condition():
    return "How are you?"

def greet(func1, func2, func3):
    return func1() + ' ' + func2(user_name) + '! ' + func3()

print(greet(hello, name, condition))`
```

when we passing the arguments(hello, name, condition), the function is not called yet. the function is triggered while we add the parenthesis(func1(), func2(), func3()). This concept is called **higher order functions**

Let me know if it helps you a bit.