# How to remove< > from the result

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[image: This is the html output from prettify]I am trying to get the list of college names from an online dataset table (search result), and the college names are in between the tag  **and** , i am not sure how to remove those from the result.

```
geo_table = soup.find('table',{'id':'ctl00_cphCollegeNavBody_ucResultsMain_tblResults'})

Colleges=geo_table.findAll('strong')
Colleges
```

I am thinking that the problem is I am extracting the wrong part because  refers to bold the line. Where shall I find the college name?

This is a sample output:

```
href="?s=IL+MA+PA&p=14.0802+14.0801+14.3901&l=91+92+93+94&id=211440"
```

Comment: By `<>` are you referring to how Python displays instances by default, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19333598/3001761?

Comment: can you share your url or html part of the table?

Comment: @WYG be more specific

Comment: @KunduK I jus t attached the screenshot for my html output.

Comment: use pandas `.read_html()`. what url are you pulling this from and I can show you in the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the `href` value you need to find_all `<a>` tag and then iterate the loop and  get the attribute value `href` to fetch the college name you can find `<strong>` tag and get the text value.

```
geo_table =soup.find('table',{'id':'ctl00_cphCollegeNavBody_ucResultsMain_tblResults'})

Colleges=geo_table.findAll('a')
for college in Colleges:
    print('href :' + college['href'])
    print('college Name : ' + college.find('strong').text )
```