# Rename a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I want to rename a function like "print" into "bark". Is there a way to do that?

I found information on how to apply another name to a library, but that's it. And don't ask about the question, the "bark" idea is just an example. I remember you can do something like that in C# and wonder if Python is an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the "name" of the function assigning it to an other variable, since in Python functions are `object`s.

```
>>> def foo(): pass
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x0000021C6B537E20>
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar
<function foo at 0x0000021C6B537E20> # Functions gets named with the name given by def, so assigning it to bar doesn't really change its name
```

So you just have to do this:

```
bar = foo # That's it
```

If you have the doubt that this may be a non-working way in some language, why don't you simply try? Open your Python Launcher, then insert this commands:

```
>>> myFunction = quit
>>> myFunction()
```

If the window collapses then you have the prove that this works with Python.

---

> I found information on how to apply another name to a library

Yes, in this case you would have to do this:

```
from myModule import foo as bar
```

Comment: Can you explain what 0x0000021C6B537E20 means?

Comment: Yes, it's the memory address of... we may say it's the address of the function, but it's quite more complex. I'll give you a link to read. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333598/in-python-what-does-function-at-mean)

Comment: And is there a difference between "import as" and assigning it to another variable?

Comment: Yes, because "import" is used to include modules, and your variable isn't in a module but in your main file.

Comment: So import basically gives it another name to use?

Comment: No, it has a very different usage, read this: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
 bark = print
 bark('Hello World')
```